# query result in python inside () and convert it to integer?

Tags: python, sqlite

my query is like this getting all rows of a table, this is for pagination:

```
totalReviewRows =  dbSession.execute(
   "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews WHERE book_id = :book_id",
   { "book_id": book['id'] }
).fetchone()
```

and it prints result like this, it looks like an array in js? but inside ():

```
totalReviewRows = (1,)
```

what is that ()? and how do i convert the result which is 1 inside of it (1,) into integer? also, how can i make a query inside of flask to just return the result 1 and not inside ()?

Comment: It's a tuple, you just need to take the first index

Comment: @roganjosh hello, i am just introducting myself in python, how do i do it?

Comment: This is a tuple. It's similar to a js array, but it's immutable (you cannot add or remove elements). You can access elements using their indexes: `totalReviewRows[0]`

Comment: thanks for ur responses

Comment: [Subscriptions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscription#subscriptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(1,)` is a `tuple`. `fetchone()` returns one record as a tuple. If no records are fetched, it returns `None`.

You can index the tuple in order to get the first element as below:

```
totalReviewRows =  dbSession.execute(
   "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews WHERE book_id = :book_id",
   { "book_id": book['id'] }
).fetchone()[0]
```

And the result should be

```
>>> totalReviewRows
>>> 1
```